# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on ZTE V817

Tags: android

I am receiving strange crashes from crash report system. It started after an update of support library from v23.0.1 to v23.1.0. It is happening only on ZTE V817 devices with Android: 4.1.2. Did anybody face same problem and did you find any workaround?

Here is a log:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=2  
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593) 
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)     
at android.text.TextUtils.isLanguageLikeArabic(TextUtils.java:1740)     
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6370)    
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle.onMeasure(SourceFile:49)  
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)  
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)     
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)    
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)     
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)  
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)     
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)   
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)     
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)  
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)     
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)   
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)     
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)  
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)   
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:135)  
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)  
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)   
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)   
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)  
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)   
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)     
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)  
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)   
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2152)  
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)   
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1863)     
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)   
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1288)  
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1013)    
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4252)  
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)    
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)   
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)   
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)     
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4814)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)     
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)     
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your code which produce StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: You're trying to get a non-zero length substring from a zero length string. That's the reason of `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Where is no code from my application, as you can see this exception happen inside android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure

Comment: Looking at the sources of `DialogTitle`, there are no differences between 23.0.1 and 23.1.0, and also none related to measuring in `ContentFrameLayout`. All the other entry points appear to be from the platform itself. What strikes me though is `android.text.TextUtils.isLanguageLikeArabic()` - there is no such method in  the Android SDK, which seems to suggest ZTE may have added it? I can only guess it's an earlier variation of `getLayoutDirectionFromLocale()` (added in the next Android version (17)), which has to do with decision-making of LTR vs RTL text.